# Trying to pull and then cross reference string API

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, request

So Pretty much I have two API's, I need to get a customer id from from an order then I need to check if the customer id does exist do not create a new one, and the other way.
When the id does not exist I get this:
`[{'ERRORNUMBER': 35, 'ERRORPOSITION': '', 'ERRORRECORDID': '', 'ERRORDESCRIPTION': 'Record Not Found', 'ERRORRECOMMENDATION': '5 is Invalid'}]`

I'm using pandas when I get the data:

`customeridget = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url)`

I was thinking it would be something like:

`if str['ERRORNUMBER': 35] in df:`

but I get: 'type' object is not subscriptable
I'm stumped, I have tried many different way's of going about it but nothing seems to be work.

Comment: `str` is a function, you call it with `()`, not `[]`

Comment: I suggest you get the API response as JSON and check if it's an error. If not, convert the JSON to a dataframe.

Comment: Sorry I do have .json on the end of request to return json

Comment: I know that. But you're putting it directly into the dataframe. I'm suggesting that you put it into a dictionary using `requests.get(url).json`

Comment: Thanks Barmar huge help, I was putting into a df to early.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for an error in the response JSON before trying to convert it to a dataframe.

```
response = pd.DataFrame(requests.get(url)
data = response.json
if len(data) == 1 and 'ERRORNUMBER' in data[0]:
    if data[0]['ERRORNUMBER'] == 35:
        print("Customer does not exist")
    else:
        print(data[0]['ERRORDESCRIPTION']
else:
    df = pd.dataframe(data)
```